# ILIKE query inside arrays of objects in jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a jsonb data column made up of various objects. Here is an example.

```json
{"LicensePlates": {"Type": "LicensePlateList", "Value": ["XXXXX"]}, "SubscriptionInfo": {"Type": "SubscriptionInfoList", "Value": [{"id": "1", "lastname": "rossi", "firstname": "paola"}, {"id": "2", "lastname": "Scicolone", "firstname": "Paolo"}]}}
```

Now I'm searching a specific info in `SubscriptionInfo` key like this:

```
SELECT * FROM column WHERE (data -> 'SubscriptionInfo') -> 'Value' @> '[{"firstname": "Paolo"}]';
```

It works fine, but I would also like to search for "partial" information, eg. searching for the string "pa" (using ILIKE or anything else similar) should return the entire record. it's possible?

Comment: if referring partial data in the nested attribute as in firstname, 
SELECT * FROM column WHERE content->'SubscriptionInfo'->>'firstname' ilike '%pa%'

Answer (score 1):

You have two options ([demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=090f911be5299842466ab68d69ef1123))

1. convert data to lower case

```sql
select * 
from 
  test 
where 
  lower(data -> 'SubscriptionInfo' ->> 'Value')::jsonb @> lower('[{"firstname": "paolo"}]')::jsonb;
```

2. Use cross join and extract JSON then use `ilike`

```sql
select distinct on (t.id) t.*
from 
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'SubscriptionInfo' -> 'Value') ej
where
  value ->> 'firstname' ilike '%paolo%';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres 13 or later, you can use a [SQL/JSON path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) expression:

```
select t.*
from the_table t
where t.data @@ '$.SubscriptionInfo.Value[*].firstname like_regex "paolo" flag "i"'
```